# I'm facing issue building MySQL query. I need to get value in end date column from start column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I'm facing issue regarding getting end_date of previous designation based on the start_date of new designation.

- Designation 1: House job officer
- Designation 2: Medical officer
- Designation 3: Doctor

If employee is promoted to next designation end_date will be start_date -1 of new designation only applicable for designation 2 and 3. No end_date for if there is only first designation(House job officer).

I'm making query but having issue on how to complete it.

```
UPDATE employee 
SET end_date = ( SELECT DATE_SUB(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Input Table

| id | designation | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | house job officer | 2022-01-19 |  |
| 101 | medical officer | 2022-03-19 |  |
| 101 | doctor | 2022-05-02 |  |

Output Table

| id | designation | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | house job officer | 2022-01-19 | 2022-03-18 |
| 101 | medical officer | 2022-03-19 | 2022-05-01 |
| 101 | doctor | 2022-05-02 |  |

Explanation

[image]

Comment: 1) DO NOT use images for textual information. Copy and paste text into your question. 2) Your title says MySQL yet you have `postgresql` tag. Pick one only

Comment: Different RDBMS have different date calculations, please tag the one you're actually using. MySQL? Postgres? To get the next row, `lead()` is typically the correct function.

Comment: I'm using MySQL right now

Comment: Which MySQL version?